# OpenMPI debugging with Valgrind and suppressions in OS X

Tags: macos, mpi, valgrind, openmpi

I am writing a parallel code in C++ on my OS X (Snow Leopard) laptop, and I am trying to debug it with memchecker. I have successfully built OpenMPI with valgrind support with: `configure --prefix=/opt/openmpi-1.4.3/ --enable-debug --enable-memchecker --with-valgrind=/opt/valgrind-3.6.0/ FFLAGS=-m64 F90FLAGS=-m64` (Ignore the Fortran flags, it's due to my Fortran compiler being from GCC).

When I run my application with

> mpirun -np 2 valgrind --suppressions=/opt/openmpi-1.4.3/share/openmpi/openmpi-valgrind.supp --leak-check=yes --dsymutil=yes ./program

I get a whole lot of warnings from Valgrind (the most of them from the heap summary at the end). I have included a small snippet of the warnings below. What I get from them is that Valgrind detects memory leaks and uninitialised values in the MPI library, but I'm not really interested in that. I want warnings from the code I write. I already run Valgrind with the suppression file provided by OpenMPI, but evidently it is not enough. How can I easily ignore all the other warnings detected in  the OpenMPI distribution? Is it possible to find a suppression file for OpenMPI debugging with Valgrind on OS X, or do you know any cunning trick?

The first warning is

```
 ==1531==    Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
 ==1531==    at 0x1014E16E2: writev (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x101AEA4C5: mca_oob_tcp_peer_send (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/openmpi/mca_oob_tcp.so)
 ==1531==    by 0x101AF0B88: mca_oob_tcp_send_nb (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/openmpi/mca_oob_tcp.so)
 ==1531==    by 0x101AC7F48: orte_rml_oob_send (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/openmpi/mca_rml_oob.so)
 ==1531==    by 0x101AC8AA1: orte_rml_oob_send_buffer (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/openmpi/mca_rml_oob.so)
 ==1531==    by 0x101B3489E: allgather (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so) 
 ==1531==    by 0x101B3525D: modex (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so)
 ==1531==    by 0x1000A48E6: ompi_mpi_init (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x1000F7806: MPI_Init (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100001AF2: main (main.cpp:34)
 ==1531==  Address 0x101a8911b is 107 bytes inside a block of size 256 alloc'd
 ==1531==    at 0x10002DB2D: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
 ==1531==    by 0x1012240B6: opal_dss_buffer_extend (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libopen- pal.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x101225CF7: opal_dss_copy_payload (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libopen-pal.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x101B347CA: allgather (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so)
 ==1531==    by 0x101B3525D: modex (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/openmpi/mca_grpcomm_bad.so)
 ==1531==    by 0x1000A48E6: ompi_mpi_init (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x1000F7806: MPI_Init (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100001AF2: main (main.cpp:34)
```

After execution a small snippet of the heap summary looks like this

```
 ==1531== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,950 of 2,194
 ==1531==    at 0x10002D915: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073888: opal_obj_new (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073808: opal_obj_new_debug (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073C17: ompi_attr_create_keyval_impl (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073FCF: ompi_attr_create_keyval (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100077C96: create_comm (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x10007798A: ompi_attr_create_predefined (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x1000737CF: ompi_attr_init (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x1000A4840: ompi_mpi_init (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x1000F7806: MPI_Init (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100001AF2: main (main.cpp:34)
```

> ...

```
 ==1531== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,952 of 2,194
 ==1531==    at 0x10002D915: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073888: opal_obj_new (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073808: opal_obj_new_debug (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073C17: ompi_attr_create_keyval_impl (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073FCF: ompi_attr_create_keyval (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x10014CEC5: PMPI_Keyval_create (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x1065ACFE6: ???
 ==1531==    by 0x10658867B: ???
 ==1531==    by 0x10017A591: module_init (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100179985: mca_io_base_file_select (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100089D55: ompi_file_open (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x1000E1ED1: MPI_File_open (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531== 
 ==1531== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,953 of 2,194
 ==1531==    at 0x10002D915: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073888: opal_obj_new (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073808: opal_obj_new_debug (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073C17: ompi_attr_create_keyval_impl (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x100073FCF: ompi_attr_create_keyval (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x10014CEC5: PMPI_Keyval_create (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
 ==1531==    by 0x1065A6210: ???
 ==1531==    by 0x106597149: ???
 ==1531==    by 0x106596AAB: ???
 ==1531==    by 0x1065AD14C: ???
 ==1531==    by 0x10658867B: ???
 ==1531==    by 0x10017A591: module_init (in /opt/openmpi-1.4.3/lib/libmpi.0.dylib)
```

Comment: Just to be clarify: I don't know if this is an OS X issue or the same on Linux systems as I haven't tested it on a Linux system.

Comment: to format code samples or program output, please, don't use `>` symbol. Select the code sample and press button "{}" at top panel. It will add 4 space symbols (0x20) at beggining of every line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to Open MPI's behavior under Valgrind, but MPICH2 should be better about this.  If you don't specifically need Open MPI as your MPI implementation, then you can [easily configure MPICH2 to avoid problems with Valgrind](http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Support_for_Debugging_Memory_Allocation#Valgrind_Integration).

Comment: I will try to look into this, so far I have only used OpenMPI. In any case I guess I could debug my code with MPICH2 and otherwise use OpenMPI for other purposes

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional suppressions yourself for valgrind. These will take care of the first set of warnings that you posted:

```
{
  ORTE OOB suppression rule
  Memcheck:Param
  writev(vector[...])
  fun:writev
  fun:mca_oob_tcp_msg_send_handler
  fun:mca_oob_tcp_peer_send
  fun:mca_oob_tcp_send_nb
  fun:orte_rml_oob_send
  fun:orte_rml_oob_send_buffer
  ...
  fun:ompi_mpi_init
}

{
  OMPI init leak
  Memcheck:Leak
  fun:malloc
  ...
  fun:ompi_mpi_init
}

{
  OMPI init leak
  Memcheck:Leak
  fun:realloc
  ...
  fun:ompi_mpi_init
}

{
  OMPI init leak
  Memcheck:Leak
  fun:calloc
  ...
  fun:ompi_mpi_init
}
```